# How to measure individual performance in a Scrum environment?

Tags: scrum, agile, performance, kpi

I would like to know if there is a way to measure the team members of a Scrum Team individually. All the measures I found apply over the team; this makes sense because the idea is to share all the work and responsibility for the increment of a product among the entire Team.

But my organization wants to have a way to measure with numbers if a person is good at his/her job beyond all the good comments of other team members' or quality of the product develop by the Team.

What key performance indicators (KPI) can we use?

Comment: Took me a while trying to figure out if 'PKI' was actually supposed to mean something before deciding it was probably a typo... this is why I dislike acronyms.

Comment: Bring it up with you team. Get them to unite and agree on being reviewed as a team. The management will have to change their ways. Before this, you should definitely give the good old coaching/presentation a go and I am sure your management will see why the team should be reviewed as a whole and not individually.

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted. Seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: Tried to write a good answer - this is just such a broad question. Let me ask, what do they want to know and why? The basic problem is that measuring individual performance discourages critical activities like assisting your teammates and cross-training. This is a pretty good 15-minute explanation. https://www.ted.com/talks/yves_morieux_how_too_many_rules_at_work_keep_you_from_getting_things_done I'm happy to throw some ideas your way though if you let me know on the items above.

Comment: @Daniel I just came across this question and downvoted it because it's about *people management* not project management.

Comment: Hi @RubberDuck, people management is part of project managament, I write this based on pmbok, if we take about Prince2, it is out of scope, but thanks for your comment, not all who downvoted explain her reason

Answer (score 6):

I can definitely feel your pain on this one. Unfortunately, it seems like the organization hasn't grasped the team concept of Agile. If your role is the SM, I would encourage you to educate the managers and directors on working differently. Agile/Scrum changes everything about the way we work, even the way we manage and review individuals.
 An example you might want to put together to show them a new way is a skills matrix of a development team member that aligns with the skills needed to perform the job. Including other SMs and HR in the process will help.

Comment: I second that. Trying to find ways to appraise employees individually is a big no no. An agile anti pattern.

Comment: I wanted to add that the Skills Matrix for the Dev team, PO, and/or SM, is essentially a grading sheet for the role. However, it allows for the focus on skills that help the team, rather than the individual. For instance, "Collaboration" could be a category with different levels. At each level, examples of displaying that skill should be given: pair programming, leading white boarding sessions, instrumental in ATDD. This will give the functional manager a and employee a clear focus of discussion, and allow the organization to promote the skill sets it values.

Answer (score 4):

**None.**

Any individual performance metrics should only be used for the benefit of the employee. Otherwise you're committing [teamicide](https://lookforwardconsulting.com/2015/03/21/what-is-teamicide/).

Do you want to have your team members help each other out on problems? Coach each other on technologies? Do you want them to give you their best estimates? And just work on what is next on the list? Do you want them to identify with something more than themselves?

These are all things you stand to lose if you incentivize looking out for yourself over the team.